# Exception Handling in C# for handling errors in the powershell script

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to call a power shell script file from C# which automates some task.
I want to efficiently handle exception that may occur while the power shell script executes and capture it in c# code.
Below is the sample code I am currently using, but am not sure if it is correct.
Any suggestions on what needs to be changed.

I also tried **pipeline.Error.Count** but the value returned is 0 even if exception has occurred.

```
                string cmdArg = "mypowerscript.ps1";
                Runspace runspace = null;
                Pipeline pipeline = null;
                try
                {
                    runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                    pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
                    runspace.ApartmentState = System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA;
                    runspace.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseCurrentThread;
                    runspace.Open();
                    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmdArg, true);
                    pipeline.Commands[0].MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.Error, PipelineResultTypes.Output);
                    Collection<PSObject> results = null;
                    results = pipeline.Invoke();
                    if (results.Count == 0)                            
                        MessageBox.Show(" Failed",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    else                            
                        MessageBox.Show("Successful",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                    {
                        // Consume the results
                        Debug.WriteLine(obj);                            
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;                                               
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }                    
                if (runspace != null)
                    runspace.Close();
```

Comment: Why can't you handle the Exceptions in power shell rather than c#

Comment: I want to make use of MessageBox to show the error to the user.